# SQL WHERE look for 2 data in one column

Tags: sql, nested, where-clause

I got 2 tables

**item:**

```
name
id
other
```

**part:**

```
name_part
id
other
```

I wish to make a query to find what item is linked with name_part = 'a' AND name_part = 'b'

2 different parts in a same item

Query:

```
SELECT item.name
FROM item
INNER JOIN table1 ON item.id = part.id
WHERE part.name_part = 'a' AND part.name_part = 'b'
```

The output us '0'

Maybe with nested `WHERE` ?

I've tried, but I can't find how to make it work.

PS: I've already ask for a similar question but it's was very imprecise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forpas's solutions are very reasonable.  This answer, though, extends your attempt.

You can do what you want with `join`s, but you need two of them:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM item i JOIN
     part pa
     ON pa.id = i.id  AND
        pa.name_part = 'a' JOIN
     part pb
     ON pb.id = i.id AND
        pb.name_part = 'b';
```

Your version cannot work, because `name_part` cannot be both `'a'` and `'b'` in the same row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your second answer.  You code look powerful and expendable. Can you give me just a bit more of explanation about your code? (or where I can find tuto). In my course (CS50 and O'reilly book) I never see that kind of build: JOIN => CONDITION 1 => JOIN => CONDITION 2

Comment: @saquiel . . . This is just a `FROM` clause with two joins.  There is nothing really special about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM item i
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM part p WHERE p.id = i.id and p.name_part = 'a')
  AND
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM part p WHERE p.id = i.id and p.name_part = 'b')
```

or join the tables, group by item and set the condition in the having clause:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM item i INNER JOIN part p 
ON i.id = p.id
WHERE p.name_part IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY i.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.name_part) = 2
```

Although I used the column names from your sample data, I believe that the column `id` in the table `part` should be renamed to something like `item_id` since it references the `id` of `item`.

Comment: The EXISTS version is really smart. I think I'll dig into the join system. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @saquiel just think about it: if you wanted a query for parts 'a', 'b' and 'c' would you use 3ple joins? I don't think so. but the answer that you accepted proposes exactly that. My 2nd query works for any number of parts. My 1st query with EXISTS should do better in most cases if you want to search for only 2 parts.

Comment: That's true. A working code is not alway a good one. I need to train myself with SQL.

Comment: *A working code is not alway a good one* correct. But if you could choose between several *working codes* which one would you choose?

Comment: I think I'll pick the clearer and faster one. But as a newby, It's hard to choose.

Comment: So try a triple (or more) join and check it if it's clear and fast.